# Visual Studio 2008 and  Lapack

Tags: visual-studio-2008, lapack

How Do I add `LAPACK 3.1.1` library to `Visual Studio 2008`? I have [found a tutorial](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/VisualStudio_install.html#download) but it is for `Visual Studio 2005`, and when trying to do it, I can not get it to work.

Comment: What doesn't work? What did you try?

Comment: In the tutorial it says to open a solution and then configure, and my visual studio says that the solution was made in an older version, so can not keep going,...

Comment: You are not getting an option to convert to the new version? What version was it created in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to convert the solution and projects.

If you can't use the [Visual Studio Conversion Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60z6y467.aspx), there are other [converters](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vspc/).

Comment: mmm, Do you know any tutorial to get `Lapack` (maybe with the last LAPACK 3.3.1 version) working on `Visual Studio 2008` (or Visual Studio 2010)?

Comment: @darkcminor - Sorry, I don't.